# Import commits from git into existing subversion

Tags: git, svn, merge

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before. Then just help me with a link.

I have an SVN repository. Somebody else converted it into git to do some work. Now, I'd like to import his commits into the SVN again. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

### The standard Git way

So basically you have to contact the SVN repo and SVN commit the work there. This is done the standard way by the following commands:

```
$ git svn rebase
$ git svn dcommit
```

You can find the details in the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)'s [Git and SVN chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/ch8-1.html).

The first command updates the local Git repo to the HEAD revision of the SVN, and plays all the commits done so far locally on top of it (*rebasing*). It is important that *this will modify only your local repo!*

Note that this might require some additional git-magic, it depends on how far did the two repo diverged (e.g., merging conflicts). But if you're lucky, it will go smoothly. *If you're not a Git-magician, do a whole backup of the local repo before doing anything :-)*

The second command then commits back all the local modifications into your SVN repo (dcommit is the *"remote commit"*).

### Alternative solution

The other way is to create a patch from the local modifications:

```
$ git format-patch ...
```

Then apply the patch for a clean SVN repo and simply commit all the changes in a single commit if the commit history is not important. Probably this is the easier way if you prefer SVN.

Comment: in the meantime I followed the instruction I found here: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit as my local repository is SVN. It worked.